# Disable css styles for single tables

Tags: css, r, shiny

**Problem:** Currently, I am using the flatly theme in Shiny. However, I do not like the displaying of the tables. Is there a way to get easily the default theme only for tables (see also screenshots)?

**Current Situation:**

[image]

**Target:**
[image]

```
library("shiny")
library("formattable")

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    theme = shinythemes::shinytheme("flatly"),
    sidebarPanel(
      formattableOutput("table")
    ),
    mainPanel(
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    test.table <- data.frame(lapply(1:8, function(x) {1:10}))
    
    output$table <- renderFormattable({formattable(test.table, list())})
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by an easy way.(; But to achieve your desired result you could add some custom css which overwrites the rules for the table styling with the default values.

To make the example a bit more interesting I have put your table inside the live theme selector example from [here](https://rstudio.github.io/shinythemes/) and used `mtcars` as example data set:

```
library("shiny")
library("formattable")

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    shinythemes::themeSelector(),  # <--- Add this somewhere in the UI
    tags$style(HTML("
      .table > tbody > tr > td,
      .table > tbody > tr > th,
      .table > tfoot > tr > td,
      .table > tfoot > tr > th,
      .table > thead > tr > td,
      .table > thead > tr > th {
        font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 1.42857143;
        color: #333;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #ecf0f1;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
        padding: 8px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        background-color: transparent;
      }
    ")),
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("txt", "Text input:", "text here"),
      sliderInput("slider", "Slider input:", 1, 100, 30),
      actionButton("action", "Button"),
      actionButton("action2", "Button2", class = "btn-primary")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Tab 1"),
        tabPanel("Tab 2")
      ),
      formattableOutput("table")
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    test.table <- mtcars
    
    output$table <- renderFormattable({formattable(test.table, list())})
  }
)
```

[image]